# Shared Preferences learning. How to save and load

Tags: dart, flutter

i found this and I'm trying to recreate it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _save,
          child: new Text('Save my list of int'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_save() async {

  List<int> myListOfIntegers = [1,2,3,4];
  List<String> myListOfStrings=  myListOfIntegers.map((i)=>i.toString()).toList();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>()) ;
  List<int> myOriginaList = myList.map((i)=> int.parse(i)).toList();
  print('Your list  $myOriginaList');
  await prefs.setStringList('mylist', myListOfStrings);
}
```

I have a list called timerValuesList in an external file imported as Options. Now I don't understand the line after SharedPreferences pref = ..., why there is another list of strings? Is that maybe for creating a List in case it doesn't exist? 
this is my file. I will make the load too.

Now I've tried to do it. I noticed it is all good, but when I use values in some widget for example timerValuesList[0], it shows me 30.0 and not the value that I 've modified in other functions and then save it to sharedpref. But if I then edit the value for example +1, it doesn't start from what it shows 30.0, but from the value I edited last time and updated. So it is the value right but it doesn't show it to me until i update the screen. Do you know why? The problem only appears when I first launch the app, after that no problem, thats why i though putting the loadSharedPreferences in the initState but still appears.

```
List<double> timersValuesList = [30.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0];

void saveSharedPreferences() async {
  // from List of double to a List of String
  List<String> convertedTimerValues = timersValuesList.map((i) => i.toString()).toList();
  // getting the instance of sharedPreferences as Object prefs
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // taking my List as key of "mylist", if it doesn't exist create empty List, this is List of String
  List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>());
  //saving the List of String as key"mylist"
  await prefs.setStringList('mylist', convertedTimerValues);
}

void loadSharedPreferences() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>());
  List<double> myOriginalList = myList.map((i)=> double.parse(i)).toList();
  timersValuesList = myOriginalList;
//    print('Your list  $myOriginalList');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you don't understand, however:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Obviously the above is getting the SharedPreferences instance.

```
List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>());
```

The above says get myList and "??" if null create an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

In `SharedPreferences` you need to put a `String` as a key to save your value.
After getting the instance

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

The very next line retrieves the list (which is a list of String) with the key `'mylist'`.

```
List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>());
```

In the next line, the code is mapping it to a List of Integer by parsing the strings from `myList`

```
List<int> myOriginaList = myList.map((i)=> int.parse(i)).toList();
```

You can

- setBool
- setInt
- setDouble
- setString
- setStringList

How to save:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setStringList('your_string_list_key', yourStringList);
```

You'll find other fuctions to save other types of value.

To Retrieve:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
yourStringList = prefs.getStringList('your_string_list_key') ?? List<String>();
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not understand when you say I don't need to parse/receive from string list if it is not a string list. Mine is a List of double values. If it is not too much can you show me how to save load a string of double values? Furthermore, do I need to make another function if I have more than one list, int etc to save? or Do I just need to add lines of code after? thank you really much for your time.

Comment: Do you mean if it is only a int, double value and not a list of those? If it is a List of something I need to convert it to a List of string and then work on it no?

Comment: yes if its a list, then you need to convert it to a List of string and then work. I've updated the answer for more clarification.

Comment: thank you. If you can check one last time, i've edited the question with an update. Thank you.

Comment: I have put the loadSharedPreferences in the initState too. but still the problem.

Comment: List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>()); // you don't need this line. while saving into Shared Preference always use the same key for the same list. (if you want to get the same values across your app)